# Mongodb how to query and update data like this Map<String, Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregate-functions

I have a document like this in my database:

```
{ "MyDiaries":[{    
            id:"diary1",
            "MyCalendar1" : {
                "Date1" : {
                    "holidaytype" : "CHRISTMAS",
                    "optional" : false
                }
            },
            "MyCalendar2" : {
                "Date1" : {
                    "holidaytype" : "CHRISTMAS",
                    "optional" : false
                },
                "Date2" : {
                    "holidaytype" : "NEWYEAR",
                    "optional" : true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id:"diary2",
            "MyCalendar1" : {
                "Date1" : {
                    "holidaytype" : "CHRISTMAS",
                    "optional" : false
                }
            },
            "MyCalendar2" : {
                "Date1" : {
                    "holidaytype" : "CHRISTMAS",
                    "optional" : false
                },
                "Date2" : {
                    "holidaytype" : "NEWYEAR",
                    "optional" : true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    }
```

and it's `Map<MyCalendarString, Map<DateString, Object>>` in Java.  While inserting the data, I have to check whether a particular diary exists and calendar exists and also whether it has the same date.

1. If so, then we have to override.
2. If not, then we have to insert the date if it doesn't exist in the calendar.
3. If the calendar itself does not exist, then we have to create a new calendar.

Please let me know how can i do this.

I have this already, but it did not work:

```
Query query = new Query();
Criteria criteria = getContextCriteria().and(CALENDAR).is(model.getRateCalendar())
      .and(DATE).is(model.getDate());
query.addCriteria(criteria);
    update.(CALENDAR, getMyCalendars());//getMyCalendars() will give Map<String, Map<String, Object>>

FindAndModifyOptions findAndModifyOptions = FindAndModifyOptions.options().upsert(true).returnNew(true);
return mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, findAndModifyOptions,clazz);
```

Comment: and what have you done so far?

Comment: Now I have added in my question, how i was trying to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Do not think about the new Calendar (even Day name) since it is a part(s) of path and will be created automatically during Day `document` insertion. Example in Mongo Shell:

```
db.calendars.update(
{"Calendars.MyCalendarX.DateX": {$exists: true} }, 
{$set: {"holidaytype": "CHRISTMAS", "optional": true}}, 
{upsert: true}
);
```

This snippet creates or updates existing.

```
db.calendars.update(
{"Calendars.MyCalendarX.DateX": {$exists: false} }, 
{$set: {"holidaytype": "CHRISTMAS", "optional": true}}, 
{upsert: true}
);
```

This snippet creates or updates none existing.

If MyDiaries is the collection name the answer is:

```
db.MyDiaries.update(
{$and: [ {"id": "diary1"}, {"MyCalendarX.DateX": {$exists: true}}] }, 
{$set: {"holidaytype": "CHRISTMAS", "optional": true}}, 
{upsert: true}
);
```

Comment: Thanks that helps, in case if calendar is a document in a collection(edited the question, please check) and have to query for particular diary and calendar and date to update or add, then how do we include this 3 dimensional query.

Comment: What is "MyDiaries"? Field in the another document? If yes where it's ID then? Or this is the collection name (?) and root documents are with ids: "diary1" and "diary2"?

Updated in case "MyDiaries" is the collection name

Comment: if {"id": "diary1"}, {"MyCalendarX this exists but Date does not exists then we have to create just a new date in mycalendarx.